# Properly Converting NSString to CGFloat, NSInteger, etc

Tags: objective-c, types, nsstring

I have a question about safely or properly converting an `NSString` into types such as `CGFloat` and `NSInteger`, considering that these are simply wrapper types that Apple created to use different primitives depending on certain factors (e.g., `NSInteger` is `typedef`'d to `int` on 32-bit architectures and `long` on 64-bit architectures).

For example, I know I can use something like `[ someString intValue ]` or `[ someString longValue ]`, but how do I instead say that I want `someString` to become an `NSInteger`, allowing the precision of the underlying primitive to be chosen by the compiler? Saying something like `NSInteger integer = [ someString intValue ]` would result in data loss if `someString` was created from an `NSInteger` on a 64-bit system, right? What's the best way to deal with this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `integerValue` instead. And getting an int will only cause a problem if the integer represented by the string is greater than the 32-bit INT_MAX, but it's still better to use the more compatible method.

Comment: That's why you should read the release notes every time a major OS version comes out.  There are always a few handy additions to classes we've known and loved for many years.

Comment: What about for converting to CGFloat?

Comment: @WilliamRemacle What about **doubleValue**? Is it same?